# Stack Overflow won't work on Chrome 77 for Mac because of text substitution support

Tags: bug, asking-questions, editor, google-chrome, osx

Chrome is [adding support for the highly requested Mac text substitution feature](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42434) where in the OS automatically converts smart quotes in input and textarea fields like:

```
printf("hello world\n");
```

into:

```
printf(“hello world\n”);  // Notice the quotes are not ASCII
```

Another example is automatically substituting three periods into an ellipsis:

```
function (...spread)
```

becomes:

```
function(…spread)
```

This makes it kind of hard to use Stack Overflow as it is no longer valid code.

For some reason this seems to only affect Stack Overflow. Other sites that have code editors like jsfiddle.net, codepen.io, jsbin.com, shadertoy.com, glslsandbox.com seem to be unaffected by this.

---

#### To test:

1. install [Google Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/) ... note: will **not** affect your normal Chrome installation.
2. go to stackoverflow.com
3. click "Ask a Question"
4. type 3 periods, "..."

#### What should happen:

three periods get inserted

#### What happens instead:

the three periods are immediately replaced by an ellipsis character

---

Supposedly pressing undo is supposed to undo the conversion from ellipsis back into three periods. That works on some sites, but not on Stack Overflow for some reason!

Also, adding the attribute `autocorrect="off"` is supposed to work as well, but that doesn't seem to work on Stack Overflow, at least when manually editing the HTML in the Chrome devtools.

Here's a bug report to the Chromium team, with a screen recording of this issue:
*[Issue 978317: Auto 3 period to ellipsis conversion making it impossible to enter 3 periods on Stack Overflow](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=978317)*

It would be good to figure out why Stack Overflow's editor is behaving differently than the other sites mentioned, and whether the Stack Overflow Markdown editor needs fixing or whether it is a Chrome issue - in which case we should request that it be fixed before Chrome 77 ships in a few weeks.

Comment: Don't know for recent versions of macOs, but I had to explicitly turn the feature on in the my Sierra's Keyboard Preference panel (maybe I did turn it off though). Also, worth noting that Safari does handle these case nicely, proposing user set replacements like Chrome, but disregarding smart-quotes and ellipsis substitutions.

Comment: Since all the other sites mentioned are working clearly something is special about stack overflow and its interaction with chrome 77 so it seems like it would be good to figure out what that difference is rather than have to have every mac chrome user manually workaround the issue.

Comment: Ah it's not what I was proposing at all no. I was just pointing out that to be able to repro, I had to change some settings, so that if others also have to, they know where to go), and also pointing out that Safari handles it correctly, so indeed there must be something odd in the interaction between SO's code and Chrome's one, but since Safari is able to handle it, I'd say it's more the beta feature of Chrome that needs a fix rather than all the website that did the same thing as SO.

Comment: I see. Good point. Yes, if Safari is doing a better job I'd love to know what their criteria is for knowing when to correct somethings vs others. I'd also like to know what makes s.o. special. I noticed [this site](https://greggman.com/downloads/examples/html5bytebeat/html5bytebeat.html) has 1 of the issues as well. Undo works there, unlike Stack Overflow. But adding `autocorrect="off"` doesn't fix it (at least not when adding it in the devtools). That site is using an old version of [code mirror](https://codemirror.net/) which the new version doesn't seem to have an issue with.

Comment: `spellcheck` seems to be the one, but apparently it needs to be set since insertion (e.g `c = $0.cloneNode(); c.setAttribute('spellcheck', 'false'); $0.replaceWith(c)`). But one funny thing is that their own dev-tools tree view editor also suffers from this ;-)

Comment: Interesting given the bug report points to turning the feature on and off dynamically depending on if you're editing a code block or not. It sounds like you're saying that's not possible currently.

Comment: AFAIA, these settings can be toggled on/off individually in each application under Edit → Substitutions. Perhaps you've disabled some of those for Safari, but they default to *on* for Chrome?

Comment: I do a huge amount of data cleansing at work. Almost all cases of character encoding problems I come across are because the Mac wanted to get cute with characters.

Comment: When I had to work on a mac in the past, gosh I hated their paternalist ways of forcing things.. If I want to type `...`, I mean that, if I would want `…` I'd do it. It often assume it knows better than you, and you always have to disable all sorts of stuff

Comment: @Kaddath Word processors on other platforms do that too. Or are you saying that _everything_ on the Mac does that?

Comment: @MrLister macOS has a system-wide setting for that feature, and all programs that use standard OS-supplied text input widgets get to use that feature "for free". You are free to turn it off system-wide, or on a per-app basis.

Comment: @MrLister I was not specifically talking about text processing, rather all sorts of boring stuff all over the place (it was some years ago already).. I guess it was a quite useless rant though

Comment: If you used VB.NET then the curly quotes would be entirely acceptable for enclosing strings. :)

Comment: @EricJ. they are cute, but not to us programmers 

Comment: @EricJ. Really?  The majority of cases I come across come from Microsoft Office (usually Word) getting cute with characters.  Macs simply don't have enough market share to move the needle IME.

Comment: It would be much better if Chrome stopped implementing changes that allowed the OS settings to override stuff in the browser. This is not the first time they've pushed some design thing from Mac OS that invariably becomes the new flavor of the month in other environments. My personal favorite design faux pas is collapsing scroll bars.

Comment: Is this something independent of the macOS setting? Because I've disabled all of that <stuff>. I know the keyboard shortcuts for the special characters and so the default is useless.

Comment: I thought font ligatures were supposed to do this sort of thing. That way you choose the font(with ligature support if you want it), the rendering is whatever the font does but the characters themselves are not changed.

Comment: @Eric J.: I would be the last to say anything positive about Apple, but perhaps because there is more to publishing than primitive 7-bit ASCII? [DTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_publishing) and all.

Comment: FFS, seriously?! Chrome is becoming worse than IE was in assuming it can just do what it wants and have everyone else lump it. These useless, breaking, "cutsie" features piss me off no end. If you want to implement some crap like that by default, then at the *very least* have a well-publicised, standard way of opting out (and not by just abusing the `autocorrect` tag and hoping you can quietly drop support for that at a later date.)

Comment: @MichaelBerry Chrome has been worse in this regard than IE ever was for years

Comment: @cwallenpoole The system-wide setting is “Use smart quotes and dashes” in System Preferences > Keyboard > Text — is that checked for you?

Comment: Hum..., nearly surprised any SOF Users are using CR as it is the worst Browser in my Opinion for "Advanced" Users because of Lack of Control... - But if Google decides to implement some Changes in CR, then pity for SOF but it's not one Site (especially if only posting on the (= this) Site) that will make them revert any Change...), that's the Responsibility of the Site I would think... (Just like each time I want to post a Comment or up-vote on SOF, I then need to start a different Browser (FF55) than my Default/Prod Browser (PM v26.3.3), in which SOF has been unusable for about 1 year now...)

Comment: @TylerH, about "It would be much better if Chrome stopped implementing changes that allowed the OS settings to override stuff in the browser." => Nope, I don't agree. You have 3 Levels: OS - App=Browser - Web-Page. It's nice to have Settings/Preferences at the OS Level (usually Date and Number formatting), that if those Settings "exist" Apps should respect or could overwrite (and force) or let the Web-Page decide (Choice of the User), but the Browser should have "the last word"... - The Browser/App will always win from the OS, and the Web-Pages will try a lot but the Browser should win...

Comment: @chivracq You say you disagree but then say the same thing I said? Pick a side :-P

Comment: @TylerH Beh no, read my Comment again... And from the Answer below from 'gman' about Safari & Chrome, those 2 Browsers should take as Default Settings the Value specified at the OS Level... that the User then can change individually in each Browser if they wish so... (And even "better" would be if each Setting (in the Browser) had an 'Exception List' by Domains for which the opposite Value could be toggled...) And of course after each Browser Update, the current Settings should be kept and not reset every time to the Defaults...

Comment: @chivracq Reading your comment again won't help; it says what I described. Seems like, from your second comment, you just phrased your first one quite poorly. Anyway, you're free to disagree, even though it's the wrong position. Maybe it'd be a more convincing position if macOS' design decisions here were good...

Comment: @TylerH Hum, OK, fair enough if you are convinced to hold the "right position"... And sorry for my "poorly phrasing", I'm doing my best to use some Language as precise as possible... - But when "fighting" about some same Functionality defined at the OS Level + in the Browser (or any App), the Browser will always win. The OS can only decide about the App/Browser: "You can run" or "I prevent you from running"... - Just like Web-Pages will often be "fighting" against Functionality/Behaviour defined at the Browser Level..., where in my Opinion the Browser (=the User's Choice) should win...

Comment: @PeterMortensen Maybe, but if their changes in support of better publishing only work in your ecosystem, they're not making the world a better place. I'd rather have straight quotes show up than a string of random-looking characters.

Answer (score 15):

You can turn this feature off by unchecking edit->Substitutions->Smart Quotes etc...

[image]

This appears to be the same as Safari except, at least for me, Safari defaults to having these features off

[image]

As for undo not changing the substitutions back that appears to be a long standing issue with S.O. implementing their own undo

- [Editor's undo does not track pastes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32924/editors-undo-does-not-track-pastes)
- [Ctrl+Z undoes twice in editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167885/ctrlz-undoes-twice-in-editor)
- [An option to disable the editor's undo/redo feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289087/an-option-to-disable-the-editors-undo-redo-feature)

Answer (score -15):

StackOverflow should not turn off autocorrect on the text fields, even though this means more user annoyance. Losing the ability to use autocorrect would be more annoying than improper quotes, as any typo left in text really distracts the user reading it.

Comment: Was your typo intentional? If so, well done.

Comment: What about in the runnable snippet fields at least?

Comment: @zero298 Google chrome should add a new setting for smart quotes, instead of connecting that toggle to the autocorrect function